# Make enter select existing or top match

Tags: algolia

We've implemented algolia for our search, but now we're trying to figure out how I can trigger "enter" to select the existing match (say you're done typing and it's a match), or the #1 selected choice that comes from the dropdown.

I haven't been able to find any good documentation on this. Does anybody know how to do this?

Example (here I want 0934 to be chosen when you click enter):
[image]

Comment: Hi Sebastian, are you using autocomplete.js library?

Comment: Yes we do use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the [`autoselect` parameter](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#options) of `autocomplete.js`.

> `autoselect` – If `true`, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the search bar will automatically select the first suggestion.

I guess, based on your question, that you've already handled the selection event afterwards, but in case you didn't, or for others that would stumble upon this question, the next thing to do is to use the [`autocomplete:selected` event](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#custom-events) to  use this selection (e.g. redirect or change something on the page).

Comment: perfect, do you also know how I could add a button next to it that would also have this result. So if they type and click on the button this happens?

Comment: You could pass a custom function to the `source` parameter ( https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#datasets ) in which you would store the current top result to be able to redirect on click. You can see the implementation of `source.hits` here: https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/blob/4b50b7f308b3404f39466cb7bbd94c87c15ebfb8/src/sources/hits.js .

Comment: You should probably open a new question if you have trouble with this implementation though, the comments section isn't a perfect fit for this.